# Explain COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

The goal is to "**Show team name and the total number of goals scored.**"

The answer is:

```
SELECT eteam.teamname, COUNT(goal.teamid)
FROM eteam JOIN goal ON id=teamid
GROUP BY eteam.teamname
```

I don't understand why we are grouping by eteam.teamname instead of goal.teamid. Shouldn't we group by goal.teaid instead to consolidate the two 'RUS' entries below into one?

The two databses or you [can go here problem 9](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation):

```
        eteam
id  teamname         coach
POL Poland           Franciszek Smuda
RUS Russia           Dick Advocaat
CZE Czech Republic   Michal Bilek
GRE Greece           Fernando Santos



         goal
matchid teamid  player                gtime
1001    POL     Robert Lewandowski      17
1001    GRE     Dimitris Salpingidis    51
1002    RUS     Alan Dzagoev            15
1001    RUS     Roman Pavlyuchenko      82
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a public question or this should be a ticket in your local system.

Comment: If teamname is unique in table eteam (and hopefully it is), the query will work fine as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, you could use `id`, `teamid` or `teamname` in the `GROUP BY` clause and get the same results.

> Shouldn't we group by goal.teamid instead to consolidate the two 'RUS' entries below into one?

Let's look at the following query:

```
SELECT eteam.teamname 'Team Name', COUNT(goal.teamid) 'Total Goals'
  FROM eteam JOIN goal ON eteam.id=goal.teamid
  GROUP BY goal.teamid
  ORDER BY eteam.teamname
```

Because of the join clause, eteam.id is the same as goal.teamid. Since eteam.teamname is distinct (no two teams have the same name) and corresponds to eteam.id, grouping by any of these fields will give the same result.

Comment: I did try grouping by teamid and it does not work. Could you please explain your reasoning why you think this is the case?

Comment: I tried out SQLzoo.net and the query works... great leaning site, glad to learn about it.

Comment: I realized I was using 'SQL Server' as the engine when grouping by teamid does not work.
When I use 'MySQL' grouping by either teamid or teamname works.
Could you test if this is also the case for you?

Comment: I did not see the **Engine** option, but yes, I was using the MySQL engine.  Very good point: databases sometimes implement joins differently, you need to keep your wits about you.

Comment: In SQL Server, apparently the field in the `GROUP BY` clause must be present in the `SELECT` clause. MySQL allows it.

Comment: That explains it! Thanks for pointing that out, I wouldn't have figured it out on my own.

Comment: Your welcome! SQL can be a lot of fun, keep learning!  Remember to up vote if the answers led to an epiphany moment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by eteam.teamname to list each team.
Then the count works within each group.

One often sees

```
SELECT eteam.teamname, COUNT(eteam.teamname)
FROM eteam JOIN goal ON id=teamid
GROUP BY eteam.teamname
```

to count the number of records in the group.
Sometimes it's COUNT(*) or COUNT(id) where id is the primary key.

The difference between COUNT(eteam.teamname) and COUNT(goal.teamid)
is that the first will count the number of records, since each record will have a teamname,
and count(goal.teamid) will not include NULLs so it only adds up the goals.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your answer. You stated that count(goal.teamid) adds up the goals. But our objective is to add up the goals scored in the first place.

Comment: You are both right! His point is: pay attention to what you count because depending on the data, you may count empty rows depending on how the tables are joined.  You will see this in more advanced topics like inner, outer, right, left joins.

Comment: @user1103294 exactly.  count(goal.teamid) adds up the goals, which is the objective.  That is why count(goal.teamid) is used in the answer, instead of COUNT(eteam.teamname), and why it does not match the group by.